# Xaml Designer not loading

Tags: xaml-designer, visual-studio-2015

today i've installed Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1 and when it try to load the Xaml Designer (even of a new project) it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception has occured
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   The app did not start. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8027025B)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.AppPackageNativeMethods.IApplicationActivationManager.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, ActivateOptions options, Int32& processId)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.AppPackage.DesignerWrtUtility.ActivateApplication(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site, Boolean isRunningElevated)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.ActivateApplicationInternal(String appUserModelId, String activationContext, Object site)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func'2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0'1.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, this fixed it:

- uninstall Visual Studio
- uninstall all Windows SDKs/Emulators
- install everything again

After that everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 2):

- If you're using an HP:

Delete the "Platform" environment variable in Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables [...] =HPD. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728169/visual-studio-2015-community-designer-shows-nullreferenceexception-for-blank-u))

- If you're not using an HP, try following these steps:

  1. Close any instance of Visual Studio
  2. Open Visual Studio and create a new C# UWP empty project (name it whatever you want)
  3. Run the newly created  "useless" project, then close it as Visual Studio
  4. Re-open your previous  project. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788071/system-nullreferenceexception-occurs-in-xaml-designer))
- If you recently upgraded to the Windows 10 SDK from 10240 to 10586, then try setting the project Properties > Application > "Target version" to Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240). ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994558/visual-studio-2015-c-sharp-xaml-designer-doesnt-load))

Let me know if this helps!